# How to add item to entities in initial state using ngrx

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I am using entities and instead of having empty entities at the start I want to add a default item in the initial state. I tried something like below:

```
const id = uuidv4()

const zeroState = adapter.getInitialState({
  activeTabId: id,
});

const homeTab = {
  pageID: id,
  pageTitle: 'Home',
} as PageInfo;

export const initialState = adapter.addOne(homeTab, zeroState);
```

It works fine in dev environment and `ng build --prod=true` also builds fine. But when I deploy the application doesn't run/load anything and instead throws `Uncaught Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup..`

Can someone tell me on how to add an item to initial entity state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately adapter.addOne doesn't work so early. But there're some alternatives.

You can inject your entity manually, the store structure of entities is quite simple:

```js
const id: any = uuidv4(); // any because of type cast.

const zeroState = adapter.getInitialState({
    activeTabId: id,
});

export const initialState = {
    ...zeroState,
    ids: [
        ...zeroState.ids,
        id,
    ],
    entities: {
        ...zeroState.entities,
        [id]: {
            pageID: id,
            pageTitle: 'Home',
        },
    },
};
```

Or you can use an effect for that, it works in prod mode.

```js
@Injectable()
export class EntitiesEffects {
    @Effect()
    public readonly data$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
        switchMapTo(
            merge(
                of(
                    new UpsertAddress({
                        address: {
                            id: 'address1',
                            name: 'Address 1',
                        },
                    }),
                    // more entities
                    new UpsertUser({
                        user: {
                            id: 'user5',
                            name: 'User 5',
                            companyId: 'company3',
                        },
                    }),
                    new UpsertUser({
                        user: {
                            id: 'user6',
                            name: 'User 6',
                            companyId: 'company3',
                            managerId: 'user5',
                        },
                    }),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    constructor(protected readonly actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

And then in AppModule

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        EffectsModule.forRoot([EntitiesEffects]),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I missed out notification for this answer, but I achieved it when a member pointed it in gitter chat to this resource https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/entity/src/entity_state.ts

Comment: I had the same issue using setAll. This fixed it for me...

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`setAll`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/a489b48d5a2ee3a645968bf67546bf03d988492e/modules/entity/src/unsorted_state_adapter.ts#L45) method of your adapter:

```js
const initialState = adapter.setAll([homeTab], zeroState);
```

(where `homeTab` is an entity and `zeroState` is the return value of `adapter.getInitialState`)